# Enthalpy of formation hydroxyl radical (aq)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, physical-chemistry

The enthalpy of formation of OH* (g) is 37 kJ/mol ([atct.anl.gov](https://atct.anl.gov/Thermochemical%20Data/version%201.122h/species/?species_number=31)). What is the value for OH* (aq)?

Comment: Would [chemistry.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic The thing is, I asked there, about the enthalpy change of OH- --> OH* + e-, and they said it was impossible to answer. That seems false to me. But they got upset and forbid me from asking anything. So, I thought I'd narrow it down. I'm no expert on enthalpy changes but it seems I can use addition, and at least that is within my competence... Like ChetMiller said, enthalpy of formation of OH- is known, -290 kJ/mol, so seems like enthalpy change of reaction should be +290 + the value for OH*. The electron, not sure how that is factored in, but starting with OH*.

Comment: Anyhow, now I might get flagged here for mentioning that. For "escaping moderation", but moderation is supposed to be legitimate, it if isn't it should be bypassed. Law of nature. Physics, hehe.

Comment: Link to Chem.SE post?

Comment: Give your opinion on if I can estimate the enthalpy change for OH- --> OH* + e- just like I can for H2O2 --> 2 OH* (here in gas phase but same principle, https://atct.anl.gov/Thermochemical%20Data/version%201.122/reaction/?&species_number%5B%5D=50&species_number%5B%5D=28&c1=-1&c2=2) and then I'll point you in the right direction.